# Local Storage Accordion-header with jQuery

Tags: jquery, local-storage, accordion

how can i save the last accordion on click , so that when the page reloads it keeps its last value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   /* =============== LOCALSTORAGE TAB Vertical =============== */
    const getaccordion = localstorage.getitem('accordion-active');
    if (getaccordion) {
        $('.accordion-header').parent().children('.accordion-body').slidetoggle();
    }

    /* =============== TAB Vertical (dọc) =============== */
    $(".accordion-header").click(function(){     
        $(this).parent().toggleclass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('.accordion-body').slidetoggle();
        
        localstorage.setItem('accordion-active', $(this).index(".accordion-header"));
        
    })

})
```

Comment: Can you expand the example to include the related HTML? ... Three accordions may be enough for a basic example. Know that you can create a stacksnippet (a fiddle-like interface) here on stack overflow. Use the `<>` icon on the edit toolbar. From the left side menu, choose jquery, 3.3.1 is the highest, but should be enough for the example. May need to add a CDN for the accordion stuff, assuming jquery-ui is used.

Comment: I can't edit more html , Looks like your post is mostly code , can I have an example here please...
<div class="tab-content">
            <!-- TITLE 1 -->
            <div class="accordion-item active border-0">
                <div class="accordion-header">
                    <h3>Title 1</h3>
                    <i class="arrow fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit nisi.
                </div>
            </div>
</div>